# macos: VSCode doesn't open new windows with git repos in new window from click in tray

Tags: visual-studio-code

Previously I could launch new instance of VSCode with selected folder as a new window of VSCode. The same result can be done manually -> File -> New window -> select folder.
But it was way faster and easier to work in tray.

[how it should work with tray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b535.png)

[as a workaround I can open new window from menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbEvm.png)

I don't remember what I have done but it gets more and more annoying. How it can be reseted? :)

Version: 1.79.2
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:58:33.551Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.5.0

I tried to open from tray a new window of VSCode with folder and it didn't work.

Blue folders will not open new window of VSCode, grey are already opened

[image: blue folders will not open new window of VSCode, grey are already opened]

Comment: this only happens for folders that are git repos? or any folder? Or folders that are inside git repos? or folders that contain git repos anywhere in them? What exactly isn't working? What exactly do you observe?

Comment: It happens to any folders. If I try to open VSCode as a new window with folder - it fails. But if this folder was already opened and I click on it as a grey icon - it works.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed by restart of laptop.